# Why set is not equal its closure minus its boundary?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Why $ \Omega \neq \bar{\Omega} \setminus \partial \Omega $ ? Can somebody show any counterexample?

Comment: This is a counterexample: $[0,1)$.

Comment: Try this one: $\Omega = \{0\}$.

Comment: Or this one: $\mathbb Q$. Or this one: $\mathbb N$. Or this one: $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any set that contains any point of of its boundary will fail this.